# How do I block or substitute a certain font in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

I have Helvetica installed on my Windows XP PC, which is great for designing, but Helvetica looks horrendous when displayed in a browser on PC.

For example, I visit a website with this style:

```
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

`Helvetica` is selected, as it is installed on my system.

Can I force Firefox to pretend Helvetica isn't installed on my system, and render these pages using Arial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other day I came across a site that used Comic Sans, and I decided I wanted to replace it with Verdana. I did some googling and found [this Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/5658) which removes Comic Sans from any website you visit. I rewrote that script to replace Helvetica with Arial

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i in tags) {
    var style = getComputedStyle(tags[i], '');
    if (style.fontFamily.match(/helvetica/i)) {
        var fonts = style.fontFamily.split(',');
        for (var j in fonts) {
            if (fonts[j].match(/helvetica/i)) {
                fonts[j] = 'arial';
            }
        }
        tags[i].style.fontFamily = fonts.join(',');
    }
}
```

Comment: This ALMOST works, I checked a Helvetica'd page in Firebug and for some reason the script is adding " Light" to the end of the font. 

So I ended up with:
  font-family:"Arial ! important Light",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

Same thing happened when I removed the "! important" and tried a few other fonts. Any idea where this mystery " Light" is coming from?

Comment: I edited my post. The new code should work. The website you were looking at probably had `Helvetica Light` as the first font.

Comment: Sorry to comment an old solution, but I would like to let you know that in Firefox 19.0.2 `getComputedStyle()` is reported as an unsupported operation.

Answer (score 9):

The following instructions do not require any plugins or addons, which is a bonus.

1. Find your [profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile).
2. Navigate to the subfolder 'chrome'. If it doesn't exist, create it.
3. Now inside that folder, create an empty file called 'userContent.css'.
4. Open that file in a text editor, and add this text (all on one line): `@font-face { font-family: 'Helvetica'; src: local('Arial'); }`
5. Save that file and restart firefox.

Just a note about step four. You may need to replace several fonts, so you should copy and paste that line but replacing each font. For example, I need this: `@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }`.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/a/532623/460302, especially regarding the requirement (at least as of FireFox 55.0.3) to use the `!important` directive.

Comment: @CODE-REaD, CSS [at-rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule) do not have the `! important` syntax. Only selectors and pseudo-{classes,elements}, i.e. those subject to [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), do.

Comment: Thanks, and for posterity, this 8yo recipe works like a charm as of FF 150.0b9 (Dev. Ed.)!

Answer (score 1):

I think [User CSS](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#usercss)/User Styles can help in that you can force the browser to override the pages style.

Some [tutorials](http://userstyles.org/help/coding) to [help](http://userstyles.org/help/coding)